# how to create front end for python machine learning model

Tags: python, user-interface

I have created a sentiment analysis ML system in python which predicts if the review is positve or negative. I want to add a form with text box feature and call python script on the review entered. Does python contains such UI features supporting tensor flow models ?

Comment: UI has nothing to do with TF. Use your favourite python UI library and just call your prediction method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use pyqt and Tkinter for UI feature

link for detail about Tkinter

https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter

link for detail about pyqt

https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt